# Make 3d Point Cloud From Video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, point-clouds

I'm looking for a way to make a 3d point cloud from a video taken with a phone.
I checked a few (open3d, pytorch geometric..) but they were more about visualizing the point cloud.
What is the best way to do this project?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about best but _one_ program is VisualSFM. you'll find others.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like @Christoph commented, what you want is a [StructureFromMotion(SFM)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRTEMKS3Sw0) job.

Some open source project is available, check below:

- [Colmap](https://colmap.github.io/index.html)
- [meshroom](https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom) from AliceVision
- [SFM from openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/de/d7c/tutorial_table_of_content_sfm.html)